# Fedora VM behind NAT can not ping host.domain name on intranet

Tags: fedora, nat, host-name-resolution

I am using VirtualBox on Windows now.

The network is roughly like this:

[Fedora 37 VM] -- NAT network --  [Windows Host]  ---- intranet ---- internet

I use DNS on intranet to resole host.domain names like both some.host.on.intranet and [www.yahoo.co.jp](http://www.yahoo.co.jp) .
On my windows host, this is OK.
But I am not so luky on my Fedora VM.

```
shao@fedora Music $ resolvectl status
Global
       Protocols: LLMNR=resolve -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp0s3)
    Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 10.0.2.1
       DNS Servers: 10.0.2.1 10.3.1.24 192.168.3.1
        DNS Domain: intra.somedomain.co.jp

Link 3 (docker0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

My primary DNS is `10.0.2.1`, which is OK, same as  my Windows host.

I can resovle [www.yahoo.co.jp](http://www.yahoo.co.jp) on Linux VM.

```
shao@fedora Music $ ping www.yahoo.co.jp
PING edge12.g.yimg.jp (183.79.250.251) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 183.79.250.251: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=17.4 ms
64 bytes from 183.79.250.251: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=20.5 ms
```

When  I try to resolve host.domain on intranet. I got:

```
shao@fedora Music $ ping dev-dm-energy101z.dev.jp.local
ping: dev-dm-energy101z.dev.jp.local: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

What makes me confuse is that I can 'dig' that host.domain name.

```
shao@fedora Music $ dig @10.0.2.1 dev-dm-energy101z.dev.jp.local

; <<>> DiG 9.18.11 <<>> @10.0.2.1 dev-dm-energy101z.dev.jp.local
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34400
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dev-dm-energy101z.dev.jp.local.        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dev-dm-energy101z.dev.jp.local. 721 IN  A       100.67.254.168

;; Query time: 11 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.2.1#53(10.0.2.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Thu Mar 09 10:27:42 JST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 75
```

I also checked tcpdump when I performed these instructoins.

I can see UDP traffic when I 'ping yahoo' or 'dig intranet_host', like this:

```
10:40:31.283922 enp0s3 Out IP 10.9.9.4.45466 > 10.0.2.1.53: 7945+ [1au] A? www.yahoo.co.jp. (44)
10:40:31.284623 enp0s3 Out IP 10.9.9.4.35216 > 10.0.2.1.53: 59710+ [1au] AAAA? www.yahoo.co.jp. (44)
10:40:31.292909 enp0s3 In  IP 10.0.2.1.53 > 10.9.9.4.45466: 7945 2/0/1 CNAME edge12.g.yimg.jp., A 183.79.217.124 (88)
...

10:45:14.514350 enp0s3 Out IP 10.9.9.4.54319 > 10.0.2.1.53: 3623+ [1au] A? dev-dm-energy101z.dev.jp.local. (71)
10:45:14.531879 enp0s3 In  IP 10.0.2.1.53 > 10.9.9.4.54319: 3623 1/0/1 A 100.67.254.168 (75)
```

But when I 'ping intranet_host' ,  `tcpdump -i any -nn udp` keeps silence.

Did I miss some config?
Any hint will help, thanks in adance.

===========================================================
2023-03-15:

I found something interesting.

Fedora just refuses to resolve host.domain names end in `local`, like:
`stg-zed2-jpe2.stg.jp.local`
or `dev-dm-energy.dev.jp.local`.

Is there a convention of DNS likes that?

Comment: Oh, I once was lost but now am found :)  Could you post a short answer so I can 'accept' it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use .local like that. It's [reserved](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) for [Multicast DNS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6762) (mDNS) lookups in an environment without managed DNS servers.

It's actually reserved for use with the full set of [Zeroconf](http://www.zeroconf.org/) technologies, but the one relevant here is mDNS.